# solving an equation in Java

Tags: java, equation-solving

Guess I´m trying to solve bit complex equation using java on eclipse.

I'm having the same answers on my print outs. can someone please help

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("enter the flr_i value");
double flr_i = input.nextDouble();

System.out.print("enter the  effective  flr_j value ");
double flr_j_eff = input.nextDouble();

System.out.print("enter the number of layer-j frames ref by a layer i-frame");
double M_j_i = input.nextDouble();

double j = 0;
double i = 1;
for (j = 0; j<i; j++ )      
    j *=i;

double flr_i_eff = 1-(1-flr_i)*j*Math.pow((1-flr_j_eff), M_j_i );
System.out.println(" the effective frame loss rate is: "+flr_i_eff);

double sigma = 0;
double l = 0;

double ni=1000;
double avgFLR_F = 0;
while (l <20){
    l++;
    sigma += l; 
}

avgFLR_F = sigma*(ni/(sigma*ni))*flr_i_eff;
System.out.print("the mean frame loss rate is :"+ avgFLR_F);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `double j = 0;double i = 1;for (j = 0; j<i; j++ )      
    j *=i;
It seems like it does nothing at all

Comment: what is the equation you are trying to solve?

Comment: Do you have a link to a document showing the equation you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 3):

There are some logic issues here

```
double j = 0;
double i = 1;
for (j = 0; j<i; j++ )      
    j *=i;
// j is always 0 after the loop
// j = 0  =>  double flr_i_eff = 1-(1-flr_i)*j*Math.pow((1-flr_j_eff), M_j_i ) = 1 - 0 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This block of code :

```
 double j = 0;
 double i = 1;
 for (j = 0; j<i; j++ )      
     j *=i;
```

will always give you `i=1` and `j=0`

I'm assuming that's not what you want (else why have a for loop)

Also this block of code:

```
double sigma = 0;
double l = 0;

//double ni=1000;
double avgFLR_F = 0;
while (l <20){
    l++;
    sigma += l; 
}
```

will always give you `l=20` and `sigma=190`.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano whoops! Thanks for catching that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because there is an initialization of 0 with multiplication, i.e. it will be always 0.

```
double j = 0;
double i = 1;
for (j = 0; j<i; j++ )      
    j *=i;
```